# Random string of characters on the front of the Meta SE page

Tags: bug, design

I just observed this random series of dots on the [Meta SE front page](https://meta.stackexchange.com):

> [image]

When I zoom in a lot, it looks like an arrangement of epsilon characters. I'm pretty sure it's a problem with the user's name because if you observe the text "answered x minutes ago by...", it's missing the username:

> [image]

It remains on top of the sandbox post: now that there are new items on the front page, it has moved downwards.

I've tested this while signed in on Brave 0.24.0 for Windows 10 and signed out on Google Chrome 69.0.3497.100 for Windows 10. It doesn't disappear after reloading the page and it doesn't show up on other sites.

Comment: Yep, it's visible on the mobile site too.

Comment: @๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎ Yeah, no idea what's going on. This is showing up in the comments for your username too!

Answer (score 3):

it was me. how can I change my username??

> Oops! There was a problem updating your profile:
>
> - Display name may only be changed once every 30 days; you may change again on Oct 23 at 5:53

`:(`

Comment: I dunno. Maybe a mod'll come by and change it for you. This is showing up everywhere your user name should!

Comment: @Chair For the record I flagged myself for mod attention. Hope they'll help me!

Comment: More relevant answer would be: Why?

Comment: @rene did you mean “why to change back?” :)